# Flutter iOS Error: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, mapbox

I'm working on flutter mapbox project and I have problem in iOS building.

Mapbox is supported  on over iOS 10.0, and over xcode 10.2.

[image]

In first building , it gave me following errors.

> error: Multiple commands produce
> '/Volumes/Data/app/guider/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Assets.car':
> 1) Target 'Runner' (project 'Runner') has compile command with input '/Volumes/Data/app/guider/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets'
> 2) That command depends on command in Target 'Runner' (project 'Runner'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”
>
> ```
> note: Using new build system
> note: Building targets in parallel
> note: Planning build
> note: Constructing build description
> warning: duplicate output file '/Volumes/Data/app/guider/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Assets.car'
> ```
>
> on task: PhaseScriptExecution [CP] Copy Pods Resources
> /Users/kk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-cihwsqtqavnxkdhbdswetypijxrb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Script-45D40599582F5CDF65637B34.sh
> (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
> build session not created after 15 seconds - still waiting

As result of googling,  I've  changed   build system  : "New Build System"->"Legacy Build System(deprecated)".
Now  I had following errors.

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
> "*OBJC_CLASS*$_GMSServices", referenced from:
> objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o   "*OBJC_CLASS*$_FLTGoogleMapsPlugin", referenced from:
> objc-class-ref in GeneratedPluginRegistrant.o   "*OBJC_CLASS*$_SqflitePlugin", referenced from:
> objc-class-ref in GeneratedPluginRegistrant.o   "*OBJC_CLASS*$_FlutterMapboxNavigationPlugin", referenced from:
> objc-class-ref in GeneratedPluginRegistrant.o   "*OBJC_CLASS*$_FLTFirebaseAnalyticsPlugin", referenced from:
> objc-class-ref in GeneratedPluginRegistrant.o   "*OBJC_CLASS*$_FLTFirebaseFirestorePlugin", referenced from:
> objc-class-ref in GeneratedPluginRegistrant.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with
> exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Please help me.  How can I fix these bugs?
Thank you.

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but recent versions of Firebase require Xcode 11